# Using Script = argv in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, argv, sys

I'm playing around with Python3 and every time I run the code `Python3 ex14.py` below and I print  the `(f"Hi {user_name}, I'm the {script} script.")` I get the `{user_name}` right but the `{script}` shows the file I'm running plus the variable `{user_name}`

```
from sys import argv

script = argv
prompt = '> '

# If I use input for the user_name, when running the var script it will show the file script plus user_name
print("Hello Master. Please tell me your name: ")
user_name = input(prompt)

print(f"Hi {user_name}, I'm the {script} script.")
```

How can I print just the file I'm running?

Comment: use `script = argv[0]`

Comment: Include how exactly you are calling your script. The way you are describing the error I understand that you are getting the username from the command line and from an `input` call. Why both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`argv` collects all the command line parameters, including the name of the script itself. If you want to exclude the name, use `argv[1:]`. If you want just the filename, use `argv[0]`. In your case: `script = argv[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of timgeb is correct, but if you want to get rid of the path of the file you can use `os.path.basename(__file__)` from the os lib.

In your code it would be something like :

```
from sys import argv
import os

script = argv
prompt = '> '

# If I use input for the user_name, when running the var script it will show the file script plus user_name
print("Hello Master. Please tell me your name: ")
user_name = input(prompt)

script = os.path.basename(__file__)
print(f"Hi {user_name}, I'm the {script} script.")
```